# Sample Skewness and Sample Kurtosis of an exponential distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, skewness, kurtosis

Is there a closed-form expression for the distribution of the Sample Skewness and the distribution of the Sample Kurtosis of data sampled from an exponential distribution?

Comment: There isn't closed form for sample skewness and kurtosis from the exponential distribution.